# Ajax login in Django

Tags: django, ajax, authentication

I want to do my log in stuff with an ajax request so that the page doesn't reload. So instead of using a form with `method="POST"`, I will just make a post request with the email and password field values.

What are the upsides and downsides to this? How do I ensure security of the credentials? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally linking to external resources isn't ideal here, but in this case the broad nature of your question, and the exact fit of a specific external resource, makes me want to recommend that you read:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX

It's provided by the Django community to answer this sort of question, and contains links to popular AJAX libraries and tutorials.  Your question didn't provide much in the way of specifics, but I'd imagine at least one of those tutorials matches your situation.

It doesn't specifically address security, but that's a *very* broad topic: to get a proper answer here you'd have to ask a more specific question.

However, if you want to take security seriously, I'd highly recommend trying to understand OWASP (Open Web Security Project) top ten attacks: https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

If you simply understand those ten attacks, and how to defend against them, you can protect a Django-based site ... or a site based on any other framework ... because  properly protecting your site transcends framework-specific concerns.

Also it's worth noting that some of those attacks can apply to non-AJAX sites also, so it's a great read even if you don't adopt AJAX.